# How to get the HTML data generated by Javascript using Python?

Tags: javascript, python, html

I'm working on a Python program to get the images from a Chinese manga/comic site. The page I'm stuck on right now is [this page](http://manhua.dmzj.com/qiyuanzui/20286.shtml).

If I use a browser to open this page, on the link "右键另存此图片", I can get the image URL, which is [image URL](http://imgfast.dmzj.com/q/%E4%B8%83%E5%8E%9F%E7%BD%AA/%E7%AC%AC01%E8%AF%9D/01.jpg). However, I believe this part is generated by a piece of javascript code, so when I use BeautifulSoup to parse the HTML source code, the image URL is not there.

So my question is how can I get the final HTML after executing that javascript to get the image URL?

Comment: Easy: you have to write your own browser. :)

Comment: @freakish Ok, I believe I got the direction at least. Right now I'm using Selenium to get the source code from Firefox, and I can get the image URL correctly! However, it really takes a long time to get a page fully loaded, I'm still learning Selenium and trying to find a solution to customize the browser and avoid loading superfluous data.